# Is it possible to write conditional check for two variable in one conditional check

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have a case where two condition need to check for disabling button.

**sample code** , the way i have did

```
<div class="{{if isallowed 'notallowed'}} {{if isloading 'notallowed'}}">Submit</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve this by using helper.

I have created helper for this and working fine for me.

**Helper 'isany-true'**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function anytrue(params) {
    return params.includes(true)
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(anytrue);
```

**Example**

```
<div class="{{if (isany-true isdisableprev isloading) 'notallowed'}}">Submit</div>
```

Comment: Alexma answer is the right choice. you can use ember-truth-helper addon like this `class={{if (or isdisableprev isloading) 'notallowed'}}` .

Answer (score 1):

I like using [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) for the general case:

`{{#if (and foo bar)}} foobar! {{/if}}`

For tweaking classes (components only), I use [classNameBindings](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/).

`classNameBindings: [isUrgent]`

This adds class is-urgent to component if isUrgent is true in component context.

Comment: I can't use **classNameBindings** because mentioned div is not parent div of component , its Icon of list component.

Comment: Can you use ember-truth-helpers?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class={{unless isallowed 'notallowed' (if isloading 'notallowed')}}>Submit</div>
```